# How to remove x and y on submit in HTML form with Image type button?

Tags: html, forms, url, query-string

I have created a form in my application as follows:

```
<form action="/search/" method="get">
   <input id="search-box" name="search" type="text" size=30 title="Search" value="" />
   <input id="search-submit" type="image" alt="Search" src="/images/search-button.gif" /> 
</form>
```

But when I am submitting my form then URL is created as below:

```
mysitename.com/search/?search=hello&x=0&y=0
```

Can anyone please tell me why this x and y is coming in my URL. On more thing instead of image button if I am changing my form code as below then its working fine,

```
<form action="/search/" method="get">
   <input id="search-box" name="search" type="text" size=30 title="Search" value="" />
   <input id="search-submit" type="submit" value="Search"/> 
</form>
```

but I need an image button to make my form look good. Please tell me how to remove these x and y parameteres from URL.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You'll always get mouse co-ordinates for a submit button type="image"

You can use a standard submit type button and just apply styles to it to change the look.

```
<input type="submit" id="search-submit" value=""
    style="background-image: url(/images/search-button.gif); border: solid 0px #000000; width: WIDTHpx; height: HEIGHTpx;" />
```

Comment: Finally I have adopted your solution, instead of coding another 5-6 or more.. lines of javascript code :)

Comment: sweet works a champ once you add in *every single style element* mentioned :)

Comment: If you want a submit a value, you can add "color: transparent;" to the style. It worked in the latest versions of Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

Comment: I had to add `background-color:transparent;` to ensure identical display, since my image had transparent pixel that looked white otherwise

Answer (score 4):

They are the mouse coordinates of the click.  I don't believe there's any way to prevent them - if you use an `<input type='image'>` then you get them.  Why is it a problem?  Can't you just ignore them?

Answering Prashant's comment: Digg are adding an `onclick` handler to the `<input>` (or possibly an `onsubmit` handler to the form) which builds the neat-looking search URL and redirects the browser to that URL, and then returns `false` to prevent the `<input>` from submitting the form itself.  If you turn off JavaScript you'll see that you do get the `x` and `y` parameters in the URL.  Clever!

Comment: I want to ignore them caz my users shares search URL of my website accross the web and hence if the x and y will come in my url then it will be a long URL which will not look good as well as its not well for SEO too. And I think they can be removed How? I don't know but Digg is doing this, just have a look at thier search page: http://digg.com/search

Comment: Your answer looks good, I think javascript is the way to strip these parameters....

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("formid").submit = function() {
    location = "/search/?search=" + encodeURIComponent( document.getElementById("search-box").value );
    return false;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set a value, for an image button, this will override the regular coordinates behaviour. It worked for me.

For example :

```
<input type="image" value="submit" src="sup.png" name="supprimer" />
```

will return the php variable `$_POST['supprimer']` and not its coordinate as image button.
Hope this trick will help you.

Comment: ... after a couple of years.