# ParametersInterceptor - Unexpected Exception caught Error setting expression 'x' with value '

Tags: parameters, struts2, interceptor, actionresult

```
package com.achala.saraswathi.action;

import com.achala.saraswathi.data.AdminBE;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Action;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class AdminLoginAction extends ActionSupport{


    private AdminBE adminBE;

    public String execute(){
        return Action.SUCCESS;
    }


    public String adminLogin(){
        if(adminBE.getUserName().equals("admin")&&adminBE.getPassword().equals("admin")){
            return Action.SUCCESS;
        }
        addActionError("Invalid username or password");
        return Action.INPUT;
    }

    public AdminBE getAdminBE() {
        return adminBE;
    }

    public void setAdminBE(AdminBE adminBE) {
        this.adminBE = adminBE;
    }       
}
```

After clicking that submit button the

```
ParametersInterceptor - Unexpected Exception caught Error setting expression 'x' with value
```

error is coming, I don't know why?

Comment: You were kind enough to format code.

Comment: I have formated the code

Answer (score 2):

I suspected that your form is using submit button with type="image". With this button it will post parameter x,y to the request parameter. So to avoid this error you can:

- Use another type of button such as  with background image
- Add x, y property to your action class

Answer (score 0):

To solve this without destroying your object model, see the detailed answer here:

[How to remove x and y on submit in HTML form with Image type button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801702/how-to-remove-x-and-y-on-submit-in-html-form-with-image-type-button)