# Weird Extra URL Parameters in WordPress Search Form

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm having a hard time debugging this problem. I developed this site ([TiltonTrailers](http://viewourdesign.com/tiltontrailers)) in WordPress about 4 months ago. I used our company's custom theme on it.

Basically, it is an e-commerce site with a lot of search functionality. I remember that all the search field was 100% working before. The client emailed us about regarding a bug in the category filter on the header. It's just a WordPress search form, no ajax functionality.

[image: Search by Category field]

Every time a user will search a category, extra `x`and `y` parameters are present in the URL. If I remove those extra parameters, product results will display on the.

[image: Extra URL Parameters]

On the homepage of the site, there's an inventory search which uses the same WordPress search form and it is working properly.

[image: Homesearch]

Can anybody help me with this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I suspect what you're seeing are the x/y parameters added to a form submit when using an `<input type="image">`.  Here's an answer on how to remove them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801702/how-to-remove-x-and-y-on-submit-in-html-form-with-image-type-button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed your search button type from image to submit and it worked. So change it and try.